# DRY react Code multiple similar functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code below, I know there is a way to make it more DRY. But I cannot seem to find out how? I can't make the State a variable. Thanks!

```js
handleChangeN(event){
  let numb = event.target.value;
  this.setState({N: numb});
}
handleChangeI(event){
  let numb = event.target.value;
  this.setState({I: numb});
}
handleChangePV(event){
  let numb = event.target.value;
  this.setState({PV: numb});
}
handleChangePMT(event){
  let numb = event.target.value;
  this.setState({PMT: numb});
}
handleChangeFV(event){
  let numb = event.target.value;
  this.setState({FV: numb});
}
handleChangePY(event){
  let numb = event.target.value;
  this.setState({PY: numb});
}
handleChangeCY(event){
  let numb = event.target.value;
  this.setState({CY: numb});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
handleChange = (event, prop) => this.setState({ [prop]: event.target.value });
```

You can then bind your function like this:

```
<Component onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, "N")} />
```

Comment: ah thank you this is what i ended up doing, Just wondering why does prop have to become the first argument? Lets say I kept it as (event,prop). How would the component look like?
<Component onChange={event => this.handleChange("N", event)} />

Comment: You don't need to keep prop as the first argument, you can have the order you prefer. the component will look like this <Component onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, "N")} />. Your function will then receive event first handleChange = (event, prop) => ... You can also rename prop for a better name if you want. I updated my example following your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
handleChange(event, code){
    const numb = event.target.value;
    const toChange = {[code]: numb};
    this.setState(toChange);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it an absolute "must-have" that you have separate functions for each of these? Would it be possible to pass in the type (CY vs PY vs FV ...) when the function is called (possibly with a .bind() method?).

This seems a lot cleaner to me:

```
handleChange (type, event) {
    this.setState({[type]: event.target.value});
}


// Somewhere later on ....


something.onClick(handleChange.bind(this, "FV"));
```

Edit: Code Duplication

Comment: I ended up going with this solution because I used bind, just wondering. how would your component look like if your handle change was handleChange(event,type)

Comment: That wouldn't be possible. By forcing the type parameter in with `bind`, it will always be the first argument.

EDIT: Well, there is this monster ....

 something.onClick(function (event) {
  handleChange(event, "FV")
 });

Comment: ahh, thank you. Is it possible to bind multiple arguments in react? thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sorry, my react skills are basically non-existent, this is just pure JS. You can pipe in as many arguments as you want after the `this`, just remember that they are the first arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is also an alternative.

```
handleChanges(event) {
  const target = event.target;

  this.setState(
    {
      [target.name]: target.value
    }
  );
}
```

Then, you can register the handler like this.

```
return <input type='text' name='N' onChange={ this.handleChanges } />
```

Whenever you change the input value of the state N will be the same as the input.